# How should I read the contents of a file respecting endianess?

Tags: io, coding-style, rust, endianness, idioms

I can see that in Rust I can read a file to a byte array with:

```
File::open(&Path::new("fid")).read_to_end();
```

I can also read just one u32 in either big endian or little endian format with:

```
File::open(&Path::new("fid")).read_be_u32();
File::open(&Path::new("fid")).read_le_u32();
```

but as far as I can see i'm going to have to do something like this (simplified):

```
let path = Path::new("fid");                         
let mut file = File::open(&path);                                                         
let mut v = vec![];                                  
for n in range(1u64, path.stat().unwrap().size/4u64){
    v.push(if big {                                  
        file.read_be_u32()                           
    } else {                                         
        file.read_le_u32()                           
    });                                              
}
```

But that's ugly as hell and I'm just wondering if there's a nicer way to do this.

Ok so the `if` in the loop was a big part of what was ugly so I hoisted that as suggested, the new version is as follows:

```
let path = Path::new("fid");
let mut file = File::open(&path);
let mut v = vec![];
let fun = if big {
    ||->IoResult<u32>{file.read_be_u32()}
} else {
    ||->IoResult<u32>{file.read_le_u32()}
};
for n in range(1u64, path.stat().unwrap().size/4u64){
    v.push(fun());
}
```

Learned about `range_step` and using `_` as an index, so now I'm left with:

```
let path = Path::new("fid");
let mut file = File::open(&path);
let mut v = vec![];
let fun = if big {
    ||->IoResult<u32>{file.read_be_u32()}
} else {
    ||->IoResult<u32>{file.read_le_u32()}
};
for _ in range_step(0u64, path.stat().unwrap().size,4u64){
    v.push(fun().unwrap());
}
```

Any more advice? This is already looking much better.

Comment: It isn't _that_ ugly. If you want to see ugly download Parrot VM source code and see what I had to do in C. :)  In all seriousness, just abstract it away if you don't want to look at it. The way I transparently detected byte order was to store a magic number (like 1234) at head of file, and use that at runtime to detect the byte order. As far as the primitives, apparenbtly Rust already provides them. (File::read_be_u32, etc.)

Comment: For efficiency's sake, you're going to want to hoist the branch out of the loop - probably all the way out to a template parameter. The `gold` linker did this and it was *huge*.

Comment: @codenheim: U+FEFF is the standard BOM and would seem to me a good choice in such cases.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - For character data, sure, good point. Old habits die hard. In 2001 when I started that work, my knowledge of Unicode was nil. Though this was more than just character data, it packed more info in the header than byteorder. It has now actually been simplfied to 0 or 1 in the current format. My goal was to use a bit pattern that was recognizable when swapped in various ways. I can see why it was a poor choice now, and why FEFF is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

This solution reads the whole file into a buffer, then creates a view of the buffer as words, then maps those words into a vector, converting endianness. `collect()` avoids all the reallocations of growing a mutable vector. You could also `mmap` the file rather than reading it into a buffer.

```
use std::io::File;
use std::num::{Int, Num};

fn from_bytes<'a, T: Num>(buf: &'a [u8]) -> &'a [T] {
    unsafe {
        std::mem::transmute(std::raw::Slice {
            data: buf.as_ptr(),
            len: buf.len() / std::mem::size_of::<T>()
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buf = File::open(&Path::new("fid")).read_to_end().unwrap();
    let words: &[u32] = from_bytes(buf.as_slice());
    let big = true;
    let v: Vec<u32> = words.iter().map(if big {
        |&n| { Int::from_be(n) }
    } else {
        |&n| { Int::from_le(n) }
    }).collect();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```